# Simulate multiple client connections to a server

Tags: c#, .net

I want to test my server as to how many simultaneous connections it can handle .. having considerably low connection problems... in other words to simulate a stress testing Scenario. How do I go about it?
Thanks for your advice.

Comment: What protocol does your server use?

Comment: the protocol used is tcp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a class called `SimulatedClient`, which encapsulates a `Thread`.  The Thread could just connect to your server, or send a HTTP GET request simulating downloading a file, or anything else you'd like.  You could create any sort of application to host the clients, say a Console or WPF app.

It would create any number of `SimulatedClients` (perhaps configurable in app.config), start them all then monitor for problems (by catching and logging exceptions - or simply breaking into the debugger) and/or perform any performance testing.  If it's the latter I would suggest taking a look at the `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` class.

With a WPF or other kind of visual app you could have a nice grid (e.g. ListView with the View set to a GridView) bound to the collection of simulated clients, with columns for things like Status, Duration, Errors - if you made them DependencyProperties you would see the results update in realtime.

Comment: @EJD, suggest you write your own answer if you think a different approach has different merits. I'd also add your approach's disadvantages too - setup complexity, effort, etc.  Pls don't downvote however, this is a perfectly viable answer.  Let's be constructive (share ideas) rather than pointlessly critical, huh?

Comment: If I had answer I would provide it because I am trying to do the exact same thing.  I downgraded because it is not a viable answer.  It's constructive because it lead me in a direction that did not work.  It is the same as a wrong answer.  I have been downgraded for a perfectly valid answer.  At least I had the curtesy to provide an explanation as to why.

Comment: @EJD - Like the OP, you're trying to simulate multiple clients, yet "not looking for a stress testing tool" (see comment on other answer), and somehow this answer doesn't help, despite the OP believing it to be the most useful? What other possible answer is there?

Comment: A stress test would only test the hardware it doesn't really test a 1000 client connections.  If you take the time to actually test your answer on an actual server you will see that a 1000 connections from a single computer is not the same as a 1000 different connections.  I have been trying this exact situation.

Comment: What?  Where do I say run it on the same computer?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a web server see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231282

Comment: i am not looking for a stress testing tool.. i want to simulate a stress testing scenario .. like for instance .. i want to connect say 1000 clients to a server, so will my server be able to handle 1000 clients .. so how do i simulate 1000 clients connection to my server..
thanx

Comment: @phen, if the server is able to accept 1000 simultaneous clients don't assume that it will be able to handle 1000 clients. Accepting connections is one thing, handling them is something entirely different. That's why I asked you if your server uses some particular protocol. You responded TCP but even HTTP is based on TCP, so could you be a little more specific? Are the clients written by you?

Comment: it uses http .. and yes the clients are the one that i have to write. ..not the server.. .. simulate say 1000 or 2000 users connecting to the server simoultaneously
and yes what i am trying to do is.. first simulate 1000 users .. and then say 1000 users clicking a url or downloading the same file from my server .. n like how many times it showed network connection problems..
thanx